# "Load Report Failed". in win application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

This code is run well in VS2010. But when i create an .exe file of this project the report file could not load by showing an error message "Load Report Failed".

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = ClassSession.con;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandText = "SPPrintRequest";
SqlParameter reqid = new SqlParameter("@ReqID", textBox2.Text);
cmd.Parameters.Add(reqid);
SqlDataAdapter dataadapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
dataadapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
dataadapter.Fill(ds);
ConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
ReportDocument RepDoc = new ReportDocument();
connectionInfo.ServerName = ".";
connectionInfo.DatabaseName = "database";
string RepPath = Application.StartupPath + "\\ReportRequest.rpt";
RepDoc.Load(RepPath);
RepDoc.SetDataSource(ds);
Program.frmprintreq.crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = RepDoc;
ParameterValues parameterValues = new ParameterValues();
ParameterDiscreteValue parameterDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
parameterDiscreteValue.Value = textBox2.Text;
parameterValues.Add(parameterDiscreteValue);
ParameterFieldDefinitions parameterFieldDefinitions = RepDoc.DataDefinition.ParameterFields;
ParameterFieldDefinition parameterFieldDefinition = parameterFieldDefinitions["@ReqID"];
parameterFieldDefinition.ApplyCurrentValues(parameterValues);
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: you may want to use try catch, to get more info regarding your error, or debug your code to find out which line is breaking.

Comment: i toyed it but the problem have still

Comment: RepDoc.Load(RepPath); from here get error

Comment: dear @user3164702 any update on exception details? Did you even try to output `RepPath` and see whether the report file is actually there?